# Question about header files and functions in separate files in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, header-files

I have a question about header files in C++:
lets say that we have a line `#include <cmath>`. I have read that this header file contains the function declarations for the math functions. However, why is it that when we compile a file with some math functions with inclusion of the header , it doesn't have any error? If the header file doesn't contain function definitions, then shouldn't we need to compile it together with the files for the function definitions in order for it to work?

On the other hand, when we have files on our own that have separate function definition and declaration, we need to compile the `main.cpp` files with the function definition file in order for it to compile.

Why is it that with header files like `<iostream>` and `<cmath>`, we don't need to do this?

Comment: you might also want to read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work (because what you (and colloquially also others) call "compile" is actually several distinct steps. You can compile code using a function without the definition of that function, but it wont link).

Comment: The process by which external variable and function definitions are added to the program being built is called *linking* (not compiling). Standard library functions are linked by default (as a general rule) and this is why you don't need to take any special action for these functions. But this would not be true of other 3rd party functions. This often catches out beginners the first time they use non-standard 3rd party functions.